# Looking for the name of this torque-arm post (to order one OTS)

Tags: torque, fasteners

It is a post that has an arm that can swing out so that you can torque on the post.  I've seen it before but not sure where!

[image: swing post]

Comment: a lever comes to mind, but why do you call it a fastener - it does not fasten anything.

Comment: Sorry, it is typically attached to a quarter-turn fastener I want to say; so not a fastener itself.

Answer (score 2):

So, this may be what you try to describe:

[image]

Image source: https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/lockdown-self-locking-hitch-pin-625

This type of device usually rely on an off centre hinge or pin and gravity to make them operate.

Comment: Seems pretty close.  Also found this one but not quite sure how it works: https://www.e-rigging.com/1-4-Stainless-Steel-Spring-Loaded-Quick-Release-Pin.

Comment: Self locking usually means an off-centre hinge point and gravity, but your question did not ask "how does it work"...